# How to print on the same line separated by space in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and wondering if I could do this like in python it can be easily done by `print("foo", end = "")`

Here is my code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var first = 0
    var second = 1
    var third: Int

    for (i in 1..15){
        third = first + second
        println(third)
        first = second; second = third
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about the `ln` in `println`.  That should give you an idea of what the answer is. - consider trying the Pyton call in your Kotlin code.  That should give you a clue as well.

Comment: @Steve Yes, it worked. I tried `print("$third, ")`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `print` function instead of `println` to avoid printing a newline.  Printing the space explicitly via a second call to print is one way to do the formatting you want.  There are others, like using a format string, or converting the number you want to print to a string and concatenating on a space character or string containing a single space.

The main point is just that you want to use `print` over and over instead of `println`, and then use one `println` at the end to print a single newline when you're done.

```
fun main() {
    var first = 0
    var second = 1
    var third: Int

    for (i in 1..15){
        third = first + second
        print(third)
        print(' ')
        first = second; second = third
    }
    println()
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
```

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad you found a more concise way that avoided using multiple `print` statements.